# O que esse simbolo significa no javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sou novo no javascript e me deparei com um trecho de código que contém o símbolo do `$` misturado com uma estrutura de `if` e `else`.

Qual a função dele individualmente, além da função de porta lógica E?

```
  if (dayOfWeek === 6 || dayOfWeek === 0 || hour <= 9 || hour >= 17) {
        $('.hours').hide();
    }
    // closed any other time than above * working from 0am -9am but none other
    if (dayOfWeek === 6 || dayOfWeek === 0 || hour <= 0 || hour >= 9) {
        $('.closed').hide();
    }
```

Comment: Muito provavelmente é o [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: Javascript permite usar praticamente qualquer caractere como nome de variável. É bem comum o `$` ser usado pela biblioteca `jQuery` como mencionado pelo hkotsubo

Comment: Pode ser jQuery, Zepto, ou até uma implementação propria, pq pessoalmente acho jQuery uma bomba mal planejada, eu criei um clone de jQuery proprio, só que usando uma série de testes de benchmark, e também cheguei a ver outras implementação, assim como a minha, que não eram populares, mas muito boas... até implementações não distribuidas, apenas usadas em sites especificos.

Answer (score 3):

Esse `$` um atalho para usar o JQuery, que também pode ser executado usando `jQuery`.
Se não sabe o que é, é uma biblioteca `javascript`.

Veja nesse exemplo o funcionamento:

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('.um').hide();  // usando o atalho $
    jQuery('.dois').hide();  // usando jQuery
});
```

```css
div { 
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="um"></div>
<div class="dois"></div>

<button id="btn">Clique aqui para testar</button>
```

Comment: Grande chance de ser, mas não é garantido que seja. O jQuery é uma lib das mais conhecidas que usa o prefixo $, mas nada garante que seja o caso do autor. Inclusive, o próprio jQuery menciona isso e tem um recurso para evitar conflitos. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ - destaque para o trecho _Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does ..._ - mais ou menos "Muitas bibliotecas JS usam $ como nome de função ou variável, assim como o jQuery faz ..."

Comment: sim @Bacco falta um pouco de contexto para afirmar com certeza que seja JQuery. Eu já trabalhei com várias frameworks, e só lembro da prototype js (http://prototypejs.org/) que já usava o `$` como atalho, inclusive lembro de dar conflito com o jQuery